# Assign null to null in Java

Tags: java

I got this piece of code from a commercial product. I believe that it will always throw the java.lang.NullPointerException exception when this.result is null. Am I right to say that?

```
private void closeCurrentResult() throws SQLException {
    this.lastUpdateCount = -1;
    if(this.result != null) {
        this.result.close();
    }

    this.result = null;
}
```

if this.result is null, then

```
this.result = null
```

is equivalent to

```
null = null;
```

while causes the NPE.

After read through some of the replies, I think the thing becomes clear. I also did a test as the code shown below:

```
public class NullTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ABC a = new ABC(null);
        a.test();
    }

    static class ABC {
        Object result;

        ABC(Object result) {
            this.result = result;
        }

        void test() {
            if (this.result != null) {
                System.out.println("do something");
            }

            this.result = null;
        }
    }
}
```

And it works just fine.

Comment: Where do you think the NPE will be thrown?

Comment: this line:    this.result = null;

Comment: Since `result` is not being dereferenced (you're not calling a method on `result`), no NPE will be thorwn. Also, assigning it a new value (whatever it is) will not cause the NPE even if the original reference was null.

Comment: I really recommend you to read an introductory book on Java :)

Comment: @kuporific Can references really be null? I assume that the values held by a reference can be null but not a reference itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go through it step by step:

first `this.lastUpdateCount = -1;` does nothing but setting a global member variable to `-1`.

```
if(this.result != null)
```

This one (*guard clause*) tests, whether `result` is `null` if not so `this.result.close();` the `close()` method on `result` is called. The guard says, it's safe to do so. After that `this.result = null;` sets `result` to null anyways.

After this codeblock, two things are assured:

**1)** this.result is `null`

**2)** And if `this.result` had something `open` it is now `close`

> if this.result is null, then this.result = null is equivalent to null = null;

`this.result =` is an assignment statement: You are assigning something to this.result, whose value may be null. This operation is NPE-safe.

Answer (score 2):

No.. 
`this.result = null` simply assigns *null reference* to `this.result`.

It will throw NPE only when `this == null`, which is...never.

NPE means you invoked a method or referred a property on a null reference. That is to say, when your code is like this:

`obj.someProperty` or `obj.someMethod()` when **obj** itself is null.

BTW, *null reference* is a special *reference* (instead of a special value or some compile-time mechanism).

1. All the null reference is identical (same reference).

   ```
   String a = null;
   Person p = null;
   assert a == b;
   ```
2. null reference is the "default value" for reference-type variables.

   ```
   class Person{
       String name;  // `name` is null until assigned otherwise.
   }
   ```
3. NPE will be thrown when unboxing a null reference variable.

   ```
   Integer a = null;
   int b = a;  // throws NPE.
   ```
4. Many JDK methods threat null reference specially.(Which is good and bad.)

   ```
   String a  = null;
   System.out.println(a);  
   // will NOT throw NPE because:
   // PrintStream.java:
   public void println(String var1) {
       synchronized(this) {
           this.print(var1);
           this.newLine();
       }
   }
   ```

Another example:

```
    String b = null;
    String a = String.valueOf(b);
    // a is String "null" instead of null reference. Because:
    // String.java:
    public static String valueOf(Object var0) {
        return var0 == null?"null":var0.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Yes, understand better now. Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

No, you are not.

This:

```
if(this.result != null) {
    this.result.close();
}
```

Call `close()` only if this.result is not null, correct.
This would have thrown a `NullPointerException` if the check would have been `this.result != null`.

The last line:

```
this.result = null;
```

Simply set `this.result` as `null`, nothing wrong here either.

Comment: if this.result is null, it is like to assign null to null, this does't work right?

Comment: `result` is a reference to a `null`. The reference itself is not null.

Comment: No, that DOES work, when you assign null to a variable you are just changing its value, as @ChetanKinger points out.

Answer (score 0):

The `result` is like a label to a memory address. When `result` is not `null`, it's pointing to some memory address where there is an object.

When you use the assignment operator `=`, as in `result = null`, you're saying, "make `result` point to `null` and I don't care what it was originally pointing at". So whatever `result` is currently pointing to does not matter, even if it's `null`, reassigning `result` to `null` will not throw a NPE.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted won't throw a null pointer exception. But after setting the result as null you try to access any method it will throw a null pointer exception.

```
private void closeCurrentResult() throws SQLException {
    this.lastUpdateCount = -1;
    if(this.result != null) {
        this.result.close();
    }
    this.result = null;
    this.result.someMethod(); //Will throw a Null Pointer Exception
}
```